# How to use parameters within the filter in Angular?

Tags: angular, filter

```
<tr *ngFor="let reservering of reserveringen | filter: datum: searchText">
        <td>{{reservering.id}}</td>
        <td>{{reservering.voornaam}}</td>
        <td>{{reservering.achternaam}}</td>
        <td>{{reservering.tijdvak}}</td>
        <td>{{reservering.datum}}</td>
```

On the `*ngFor` in the picture above I want to use 2 filter parameters, but I keep getting an error. Can anyone tell me what to do?

The error I get

> Invalid number of arguments, expected 2

Comment: filter hmm... from vuejs (edit, oh wait, you could be from angular1.x?)? have in angular they are called pipes. aside from a few built in pipes (number, etc), you will have declare them in your modules. edit: have you build/declared any pipes in your module?

Comment: No, but with 1 argument it works

Comment: aww, so the `filter` pipe does work... try this? `*ngFor="let reservering of reserveringen | filter: datum | filter: searchText"`

Comment: IT Worked! THanks so much! :)